# SQL query not returning expect result

Tags: mysql

I wrote the following query to return some statistics about purchases made in the X amount of time. But for some reason every "COUNT" column return the total number of rows. Did I organize the query incorrectly?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countTotal, SUM(`cost`) as cost, COUNT(`paymentType` = 'credit') as count_credit, COUNT(`paymentType` = 'cash') as count_cash 
FROM `purchase` WHERE `date` >= '2011-5-4'
```

**update**

I just decided to use sub-queries. This is what I ended up with.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as countTotal,
SUM(`cost`) as cost, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `purchase` WHERE `paymentType` = 'credit') as count_credit, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `purchase` WHERE `paymentType` = 'cash') as count_cash 
FROM `purchase` WHERE `date` >= '2011-5-4'
```

**update2**

Used ypercubes answer below.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I don't think you can use expressions like `paymentType = 'credit'` in the `COUNT` function. I think you'll need to use subqueries (or user-defined functions) instead.

Comment: If you had 100 rows satisfying the date criteria, and 50 of them were paymentType='credit', would you expect the result `100, X, 50` where `X` was the sum of all 100 rows? Or would `X` be the sum of the credit payments only?

Comment: If I had 100 total rows 50 credit and 50 cash all 1$ each, I would like to say the follwoing:
100, 100, 50, 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look correct but changing `COUNT()` to `SUM()` works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countTotal
     , SUM(cost) AS cost
     , SUM(paymentType = 'credit') AS count_credit   --- SUM does counting here
     , SUM(paymentType = 'cash') AS count_cash       --- and here
FROM purchase
WHERE `date` >= '2011-05-04'
```

Explanation: `True == 1` and `False == 0` for MySQL.

Comment: Bingo, thats what I was really looking for. Thank you sooo much. Man, @ypercube this is the second time you saved me. You are the man.

Answer (score 4):

count does return the number of rows for the domain or group queried.  Looks like you need to group by PaymentType to achieve what you are looking for.

```
SELECT PaymentType, COUNT(*) as countTotal, SUM(`cost`) as cost, 
FROM `purchase` 
WHERE `date` >= '2011-5-4' 
Group by PaymentType
```

here is a reference
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a GROUP BY clause after your WHERE clause